# Update Query in MongoDB with where conditions

Tags: mongodb

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("510902fb7995fe3504000002"),
"name" : "Gym",
"status" : "1",
"whichs" : [
    {
        "name" : "American",
        "status" : "1"
    }
]
}
```

Above is my collection object.. I want to update which.name to "Indian" where which.status = 1.. Please help me with the mongoDB query for doing this..

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
db.collection.update({"whichs.status" : "1" }, 
                     {$set : { "whichs.$.name" : "Indian"},
                     false,
                     true);
```

This finds `"whichs.status" : "1"` then sets `"whichs.$.name" : "Indian"` for all documents. For more info on the update() method, read [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MongoDB v3.6, you can use [`arrayFilters`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-array-elements-that-match-arrayfilters), to perform array update operation.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "whichs.status": "1"
},
{
  $set: {
    "whichs.$[element].name": "Indian"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element.status": "1"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ePR4zMjDWkT)